# C++ Windows decimal to UTF-8 Character Conversion

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, unicode, utf-8

I've been using the function below to convert from the decimal representation of unicode characters to the UTF8 character itself in C++. The function I have at the moment works well on Linux / Unix system but it keeps returning the wrong characters on Windows.

```
void GetUnicodeChar(unsigned int code, char chars[5]) {
    if (code <= 0x7F) {
        chars[0] = (code & 0x7F); chars[1] = '\0';
    } else if (code <= 0x7FF) {
        // one continuation byte
        chars[1] = 0x80 | (code & 0x3F); code = (code >> 6);
        chars[0] = 0xC0 | (code & 0x1F); chars[2] = '\0';
    } else if (code <= 0xFFFF) {
        // two continuation bytes
        chars[2] = 0x80 | (code & 0x3F); code = (code >> 6);
        chars[1] = 0x80 | (code & 0x3F); code = (code >> 6);
        chars[0] = 0xE0 | (code & 0xF); chars[3] = '\0';
    } else if (code <= 0x10FFFF) {
        // three continuation bytes
        chars[3] = 0x80 | (code & 0x3F); code = (code >> 6);
        chars[2] = 0x80 | (code & 0x3F); code = (code >> 6);
        chars[1] = 0x80 | (code & 0x3F); code = (code >> 6);
        chars[0] = 0xF0 | (code & 0x7); chars[4] = '\0';
    } else {
        // unicode replacement character
        chars[2] = 0xEF; chars[1] = 0xBF; chars[0] = 0xBD;
        chars[3] = '\0';
    }
}
```

Can anyone provide an alternative function or a fix for the current function I'm using that will work on Windows?

--UPDATE--

```
INPUT: 225
OUTPUT ON OSX: á
OUTPUT ON WINDOWS: ├í
```

Comment: Just use the provided winapi function for this, WideCharToMultiByte() with CP_UTF8.

Comment: `WideCharToMultiByte()` takes a UTF-16 string as input, not a 32bit codepoint.

Comment: @Francis: please show an example `code` value and its output that you feel is not being converted correctly.

Comment: Your program is outputting UTF-8, but that's not what the Windows console uses. To get it to work on Windows requires a completely different conversion. @HansPassant has the best suggestion if you replace CP_UTF8 with the proper code page.

Comment: Have a look at this page on MSDN: [Console Code Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682064.aspx)

Comment: See boost::nowide, and http://utf8everywhere.org

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't show your code for printing, but presumably you're doing something like this:

```
char s[5];
GetUnicodeChar(225, s);
std::cout << s << '\n';
```

The reason you're getting okay output on OS X and bad output on Windows is because OS X uses UTF-8 as the default encoding and Windows uses some legacy encoding. So when you output UTF-8 on OS X, OS X assumes (correctly) that it's UTF-8 and displays it as such. When you output UTF-8 on Windows, Windows assumes (incorrectly) that it's some other encoding.

You can simulate the problem on OS X using the `iconv` program with the following command in Terminal.app

```
iconv -f cp437 -t utf8 <<< "á"
```

This takes the UTF-8 string, reinterprets it as a string encoded using Windows code page 437, and converts that to UTF-8 for display. The output on OS X is `├í`.

For testing small things you can do the following to properly display UTF-8 data on Windows.

```
#include <Wincon.h>

#include <cstdio>

char s[5];
GetUnicodeChar(225, s);

SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
std::printf("%s\n", s);
```

Also, parts of Windows' implementation of the standard library don't support output of UTF-8, so even after you change the output encoding code like `std::cout << s` still won't work.

---

On a side note, taking an array as a parameter like this:

```
void GetUnicodeChar(unsigned int code, char chars[5]) {
```

is a bad idea. This will not catch mistakes such as:

```
char *s; GetUnicodeChar(225, s);
char s[1]; GetUnicodeChar(225, s);
```

You can avoid these specific problems by changing the function to take a reference to an array instead:

```
void GetUnicodeChar(unsigned int code, char (&chars)[5]) {
```

However in general I'd recommend just avoiding raw arrays altogether. You can use `std::array` if you really want an array. You can use `std::string` if you want text, which IMO is a good choice here:

```
std::string GetUnicodeChar(unsigned int code);
```

Answer (score 2):

The function is correct. The output presumably isn't, which means there's a bug in that routine. But you don't show it. I'll bet that you're assuming that Windows can print UTF-8.

Comment: how can I print UTF-8 in Windows?

Comment: Well, not. That's why I wrote the last sentence. You would have to convert your UTF-8 again, now to a format that Windows can print. I.e. UTF-16. But why not convert it directly, then?

Comment: what i do to that function to convert it to utf-16?

Comment: The real question is - do you WANT your function to output UTF-8? If so, then there is no need to change it. Leave it as UTF-8, and then convert the UTF-8 data to UTF-16 when outputting it to the console. On the other hand, if the function is only being used for console output and nothing else, then rewrite it to encode the codepoint in UTF-16 instead of UTF-8. The [UTF-16 page on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf-16#Example_UTF-16_encoding_procedure) explains the encoding algorithm.