# Binary to UTF-8 in C

Tags: c, linux, unicode, utf-8

I am working on an application in C where I need to show Unicode UTF-8 characters. I am getting the values as a binary byte stream as 11010000 10100100 as character array which is the Unicode character "Ф".

I want to store and display the character. I tried to convert the binary to a hexadecimal character array. But printing with

```
void binaryToHex(char *bData) {
    char hexaDecimal[MAX];
    int temp;
    long int i = 0, j = 0;
    while (bData[i]) {
        bData[i] = bData[i] - 48;

        ++i;
    }

    --i;
    while (i - 2 >= 0) {
        temp = bData[i - 3] * 8 + bData[i - 2] * 4 + bData[i - 1] * 2 + bData[i];
        if (temp > 9)
            hexaDecimal[j++] = temp + 55;
        else
            hexaDecimal[j++] = temp + 48;
        i = i - 4;
    }

    if (i == 1)
        hexaDecimal[j] = bData[i - 1] * 2 + bData[i] + 48;
    else if (i == 0)
        hexaDecimal[j] = bData[i] + 48;
    else
        --j;

    printf("Equivalent hexadecimal value: ");
    char hexVal[MAX];
    // size_t len = j+1;
    int k = 0;;
    while (j >= 0) {
        char *ch = (char*)hexaDecimal[j--];
        if (j % 2 == 0) {
            hexVal[k] = '\\';
            k++;
            hexVal[k] = 'x';
            k++;
        }
        printf("\nkk++Length %d ...J= %d.. ", k, j);
        hexVal[k] = ch;
        k++;
        printf("%c", ch);
    }
    printf("KKKK+=== %d", k);
    hexVal[k] = NULL;

    // printf("\nkk++Length %d",strlen(hexVal));
    printf("\nMM+-+MM %s===\n ..>>>>", hexVal);
}
```

Only showing the value as \xD0\xA4. I did string manipulation for that.
But when writing in the way

```
 char s[]= "\xD0\xA4";
         OR
 char *s= "\xD0\xA4";
 printf("\n %s",s);
```

producing the desired result that is printing the character "Ф". How can I get the correct string dynamically? Is there any library for this in C?

The code is from http://www.cquestions.com/2011/07/binary-to-hexadecimal-conversion-in.html.

Is there a way to print it from binary directly or from a HEX value. Or is there an alternative for that?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to accomplish. Either you want to print the character or you want to convert to hex. For the latter it does not matter which encoding you use.

Comment: Please show more code. We cannot help with only those elements.

Comment: for now I want to print the character from the Binary stream of 11010000 10100100 .can you  assist me how to do it.After then I can try to accomplish the later one

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25033430/how-to-iterate-through-unicode-characters-and-print-them-on-the-screen-with-prin?rq=1

Comment: The backslash-x stuff is a compile time thing only called an escape sequence.   Trying to make a string with an escape sequences in it will not give you the binary characters that escape sequence would describe at compile time

Comment: When you say binary do you mean actually binary (ie, `int`) or pretend string binary (ie, `char *bin = "10010110"`)

Comment: @Sanchke It is char*...  But now  i think i should convert it to int if it helps to

Comment: @infixed thanks for sharing the knowledge.i will try to use escape character wisely next time :)

Comment: @Boiethios thank you for sharing the link.i will try to implement it that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last converting the Unicode binary char array to actual binary codepoint like converting 
11010000 10100100 to  10000 100100 and then converting to decimal and then to Unicode solved my problem for now.below is the link I use to convert to UTF8 from decimal.

[C++ Windows decimal to UTF-8 Character Conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23476598/c-windows-decimal-to-utf-8-character-conversion)

**resources I used:**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vLBtrd9Ar28

http://www.zehnet.de/2005/02/12/unicode-utf-8-tutorial/

Answer (score 4):

Escape codes such as `\xD0` are interpreted *by the compiler* when encountered in the value of *a character or string literal*.  The compiler replaces them with the corresponding byte (or byte sequence in some cases).  They are not meaningful to C at runtime.

You are therefore not only making it harder on yourself but doing altogether the wrong thing by constructing and printing the text of such escape sequences at runtime.  What you get is exactly what you should expect.  Just print the literal byte sequence you decode from the program input, without any dress-up.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually my input adapter converted the whole byte stream to char * array..i will try to get the raw byte before conversation.